# Possibilities for creating programs with Python for graph processing in Tinkerpop

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm just starting out with Tinkerpop and looking for the best way to achieve the following:

- in the beginning, there is a small '**starting-graph**'
- a couple of **scripts**, each having some **functions**, will interact with this graph
- each **script** will:
- 1) read and **interpret** nodes, edges, their attributes and ideally also perform some network metrics to understand the 'current structure'
- 2) based on rules in the functions, **update** (properties of) nodes & edges
- within each script, there is also some interaction between the functions, in terms of "if these nodes are >x, call function B"
- the problem-set is actually a bit larger than this..

But understanding how to work on (simultaneously running instances of) scripts for graph traversal / interpretation / updating is already *very* valuable.

I prefer to use Python, but willing to dive into other things if needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend spending some time getting familiar with Gremlin.

The Apache TinkerPop project includes support for Python. You can find details here [1] and can install using Pip. You may also find the information at [2] useful as well as the official TinkerPop docs.

[1] http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python

[2] https://github.com/krlawrence/graph

Comment: Thank you so much - I will read the material! Perhaps just to make sure: what I described is indeed more or less possible?

Comment: What you are describing sounds very much in line with a graph use case yes.

Comment: Thanks! Will dive into the documentation.